# Почему не работает проверка логина

Tags: php, html, javascript

У кого работает этот код?

Я хочу проверить есть ли такой логин в БД, без перезагрузки страницы

Файл LoginExists.php

```
        <?php
      require_once('select_db.php'); 
       if(isset($_POST['login']) && is_string($_POST['login'])) {
$login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
if(!mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT login FROM datacenter WHERE login=' . $login))) {
     echo 'Логин '. $login .' - cвободен'; 
 }
 else {
      echo 'К сожалению логин '. $login .' - занят';
 }
}
         ?>
```

Файл reg.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="home_page.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            function liveLoginCheckInit() {
                var loginInput = document.getElementById("loginInput");
                request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("loginCheckResult").innerHTML = this.responseText
                    }
                }
                loginInput.addEventListener("blur", function () {

                    request.open("/LoginExists.php", "POST", true);
                    request.setRequestHeader("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    request.send("login=" + this.value);

                }, false)
            }

            window.addEventListener("load", liveLoginCheckInit, false);
        </script>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251"/>

     </head>
     <body>

               <form method="POST" action="parent.php">
                <input id="login" pattern="[0-9]{10}" maxlength="10" placeholder="Логин" class="teacher_reg" type="text" name="login" size="40" required></br>                  
                <input id="password" placeholder="Пороль" pattern="[A-Za-z]{6,}" maxlength="20" class="teacher_regs" type="text" name="password" size="40" required>
                    <p><span id="loginCheckResult"></span></p>
                       <input type="submit" id="teacher_enter2" onclick="" value="Зарегестрироватся"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Проверка чего на что?

Comment: Что именно не работает...

И откуда берутся POST данные которые вы в сессию ложите?О_о

Comment: скрипт **LoginExists** находится в корне сайта?

Comment: >> Я хочу проверить есть ли такой логин в БД, без перезагрузки страницы. Не работает проверка логина, без перезагрузки сервера

хоть в меморис добавляй :D

Comment: Появилась мысль... ТС - вы случайно не Internet Explorer юзаете?

Если да - замените `addEventListener` на `attachEvent`

Comment: да, скрипт находится в корне сайта) @AlexWindHope так у тебя работает этот код

Comment: проблема мне кажется в
 LoginExists.php

Comment: Не у мя Хром, а ты в ВК есть?

Comment: обновил ответ, терь точно будет работать

PS: браузер правильный :)

vk: http://vkontakte.ru/id25620273

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['name_parent']) && $_POST['name_parent'] ) 
// добавил проверку на пустоту т.к. раньше не было :)
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['name_parent'])) {
        $_SESSION['name_parent'] = $_POST['name_parent'];
    }
// И т.д.
}
```

Для того чтобы проверка начала работать! Ручками дописать для всех $_POST и $_SESSION

Comment: AlexWindHope ошибка синтаксиса после вашего UPD а минус будет зачислен мне)))

Comment: Сорри, кстати довольно часто в isset начинаю писать &&... ^.^

Comment: все равно не работает

Comment: И не будет работать пока вы нормально не обьясните **ЧТО ИМЕННО НЕ РАБОТАЕТ**

Comment: Я хочу проверить есть ли такой логин в БД, без перезагрузки страницы

Comment: Ну и как вы проверяли... Вы знаете что проверка записана на событии **bllur**, вы "его вызываете"?

В javascript консоли ошибок нет? Что отвечает сервер?

Никаких сведений, просто выгрузили кучу некрасивого кода и ждете ответа не описав проблемы

Comment: Undefined index видите? Включите Error Reporting на всякий случай)

Comment: а вы не ленивый ....

`if(isset($_POST['name_parent']) && $_POST['name_parent'] ) `

разве

`if(!empty($_POST['name_parent'])`

не проще ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Опечатка

```
 'SELECT login FROM datacenter WHERE login=' . $login
```

Надо

```
 'SELECT login FROM datacenter WHERE login="' . $login . '"'
```

**UPD**

И как это никто не увидел?..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

function liveLoginCheckInit() {
    var loginInput = document.getElementById("loginInput");
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("loginCheckResult").innerHTML = this.responseText
        }
    }
    loginInput.addEventListener("blur", function () {

    request.open("POST", "/response.php", true);
    //  тут было перепутано местами
    //  метод и url... И как это никто не заметил :)

    //   а тут забыл Content-Type добавить...
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send("login=" + this.value);

    }, false)
}
    window.addEventListener("load", liveLoginCheckInit, false);

</script>
```

PS: этот точно работает :)

Comment: все равно не работает

Comment: Вы смотрели консоль? уходит ли запрос? нет ли ошибок на сервере?

Comment: я через консоль не шарю с mysql работать, я работаю по пхпхмойадмин или через сам код

Comment: Блин, таки лулзы проскакивают :) Имелась ввиду консоль javascript, наверное :)

Comment: Да имеется введу именно javascript консоль... ( для меня это просто очевидно, теперь понял что необходимо уточнять \*.\* )

Answer (score 0):

[[@Zow](/users/4425/zow)](/users/4425/zow), ты неделю уже паришься со 2ым скриптом. Может зайдешь на фриланс?=) Или у тебя такая особая форма обучения?)
У тебя код:

```
$login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
if(!mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT login FROM datacenter WHERE login=' . $login))) {
     echo 'Логин '. $login .' - cвободен'; 
 }
 else {
      echo 'К сожалению логин '. $login .' - занят';
 }
```

Так вот mysql_fetch_assoc() формирует ассоциативный массив. в твоем случае он вернет array('login' => 'что-то либо ничего'). Это тебе и нужно проверить. то есть как-то так

```
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT login FROM datacenter WHERE login=' . $login))

if($row['login']) {
             echo 'Логин '. $login .' - cвободен'; 
         }
         else {
              echo 'К сожалению логин '. $login .' - занят';
         }
```

Comment: + с js у тебя вообще не пойми что. Кусками выдернуто с разных источников. Ну не для тебя это. Признай уже))

Comment: ОМФГ

@Виталий Кустов - уберите сей "ответ" и не позорьтесь...

У нас приходит $_POST['login'], мы делаем выборку и если выборка пустая, то мы, грубо говоря пишем **внимание!!! причем тут `$row['login']`**
Сначала обоаботаем $login: `$login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login'])`

    echo 'Логин ' . $login . ' свободен'; 

Если же `mysql_fetch_assoc` вернет не пустой массив мы можем просто вывести

    echo 'Логин ' . $login . ' занят';

Вообщем ваш ответ ниачем ваапсче ^.^

Comment: @Виталий Кустов я ток сегодня задал вопрос по этому скрипту

Answer (score 0):

1. Хватит "велосипедить". Вдобавок, он у Вас с квадратными колёсами и без седушки, и, почему-то, педали на руле... Юзайте jQuery для послания запроса на сервер.
2. В серверной части (это файл PHP) сделайте проверку на то, что это "ajax-запрос": <code>переменная $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']</code>.
3. Строки в MySQL правильнее, пусть и медленнее сравнивать с помощью `LIKE`.

Comment: юзайте prototype, не юзайте jquery ^^

По поводу "велосипедить" - человек учится, если сразу взять и тупо начать юзать чето типа $.post - ума в голове не прибавится и всеравно будешь долго и печально тупить над кодом...

Это инфа 100%. Тут надо сначало основательно разобратся что к чему, а потом уже садится за фреймворки...

В данном примере строки правильнее сравнивать с помощью like?O_O 
т.е. если я введу логин `alex`
Он будет свободен, но будет занят, например alex100500olololo
Мне выдаст что логин занят, в чем же тут правильность то?

Answer (score -1):

так сразу в лоб

```
 window.addEventListener("load", liveLoginCheckInit, false);
```

а синтаксис у addEventListener

```
element.addEventListener( имя_события, обработчик, фаза)
```

Я бы посоветовал сделать нормальный обработчик на ввод символов в

```
  <input id="login" pattern="[0-9]{10}" maxlength="10" placeholder="Логин" class="teacher_reg" type="text" name="login" size="40" required>
```

ввел пользователь минимальную длину логина (5 символов допустим) и давай проверять на соответствие в БД.
[[@Zow](/users/4425/zow)](/users/4425/zow) показывай уже результат того что ты там ваяешь, по всем твоим вопросам получены правильные ответы, я бы уже давно сайт написал. ;)

Comment: уважаемый @Shrek - почитайте о [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) и не пишите ниачем...

И да, что вы подразумеваете под словом фаза?

Comment: useCapture true false если что.

не нужно ставит себя выше всех @AlexWindHope почти все комменты от вас так или иначе показывают ваше превосходство над всеми. все ошибаются, не нужно так "ехидно улыбаться"

Comment: Я не ставлю себя выше всех, просто очевидно что проблема здесь не в этом.

или вы хотите сказать что код не работает именно изза такого `addEventListener`?

[sarkazm]писал ехидно улыбаясь[/sarkzm]

Comment: Манией величия страдает человек, хотя матчасть (или понимание сути вопроса) хромает у самого. Предела совершенству нет, сударь.

Comment: В чем хромает моя матчасть и(или) понимание вопроса?

про предел совершенства - солидарен, сударь...

Comment: Просто вы не понимаете, что есть люди, которые только начинают делать первые шаги в какой-то области. Сразу показывать, что вы "умник" не стоит. Лучше не говорить людям о их недостатках в той области, в которой вы якобы сильны, а помочь действительно глубоко развернутым ответом, чтобы в нем проявить свой ум и помочь тому, кто нуждается в совете.